# Specs2 unable to find my tests using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2

I have build a simple project for Spec2 testing using simple sbt.

```
package main.specs

import org.specs2._

class QuickStartSpec extends Specification {
  def is = s2"""
    This is my first specification
    it is working                 $ok
    really working!               $ok
                             """
}
```

And here is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "QuickStartSpec"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6.5" % "test")

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")
```

But when I run this command in sbt

```
 testOnly main.specs.QuickStartSpec
```

I am getting this:

```
[info] Updating {file:/Users/nabajeet/workspace/SpecsTest/}specstest...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for test:testOnly
```

I am following this page to create the example:
https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/website/SPECS2-3.6.5/quickstart.html

I am unable to figure out the reason why my tests are not detected.

My sbt version in 0.13.8

Comment: can you provide the directory and file layout for your project ? I suspect the tests are not in the correct location. In a vanilla sbt project `QuickStartSpec.scala` should be in `/Users/nabajeet/workspace/SpecsTest/src/test/scala/main/specs/QuickStartSpec.scala` (well it could be anywhere under `/Users/nabajeet/workspace/SpecsTest/src/test/scala/` as package names don't have to be represented in the fs structure)

Comment: /Users/nabajeet/workspace/SpecsTest/src/main/specs/quickStartSpec.scala

Answer (score 1):

By declaring

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6.5" % "test")
```

You restrict the scope of `specs2` to only classes in the test source directories. You won't be able to reference `specs2` classes in the production code (all the code under `src/main/`)

In your comment you indicate that you placed your spec in `/Users/nabajeet/workspace/SpecsTest/src/main/specs/quickStartSpec.scala`

Try moving your file to /Users/nabajeet/workspace/SpecsTest/src/**test/scala**/specs/quickStartSpec.scala

The incorrect location is why it you spec not picked up by SBT (and I feel confident to say that it doesn't compile either).

By default, SBT applies maven's [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) adding `src/main/scala/` and `src/test/scala/` for scala code. This is documented in the [SBT tutorial](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Directories.html)

I just created a project with the following layout

```
.
./built.sbt
./src
./src/test
./src/test/scala
./src/test/scala/QuickStartSpec.scala
```

build.sbt contains

```
name := "QuickStartSpec"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6.5" % "test")

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")
```

and QuickStartSpec.scala contains

```
package main.specs

import org.specs2._

class QuickStartSpec extends Specification {
  def is = s2"""
    This is my first specification
    it is working                 $ok
    really working!               $ok
                             """
}
```

here is the sbt output I get

```
sbt
[info] Set current project to QuickStartSpec (in build file:/tmp/stack/)
> test:compile
[info] Updating {file:/tmp/stack/}stack...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/stack/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.4. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 6.372 s
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed 27 nov. 2015 06:38:26
> test
[info] QuickStartSpec
[info]     + This is my first specification
[info]       it is working
[info]     + really working!
[info]
[info] Total for specification QuickStartSpec
[info] Finished in 17 ms
[info] 2 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
[info]
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 27 nov. 2015 06:38:31
>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jean but now I am getting compilation error!!!                                   `[error] exception during macro expansion: 
[error] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Position.end on class scala.reflect.internal.util.OffsetPosition
[error]  at scala.reflect.internal.util.Position.end(Position.scala:126)
[error]  at org.specs2.specification.create.S2Macro$$anonfun$2.apply(S2Macro.scala:29)`

Comment: I tried changing the scala version to 2.11.4 for resolving this problem as mentioned in some solutions, but that again made specs unable to detect the tests!!!